# Using calc and \year to get the years from a start date automatically in text?

Tags: calculations, datetime

I would like to say, "I have played piano for 23 years" -- but this document will have to be changed every year so I remember to make it 23, then 24, then 25. Is there a way to do something like:

```
I have played piano for \calculate{\year - 1986} years.
```

Perhaps using the `calc` package and the `\year` command? I haven't been able to figure this out.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use the integer arithmetic of TeX too.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
I've played the piano for \number\numexpr\year-1986\relax~years.
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

Just in case you are going to use `tikz` in your document, here is an overkill solution with this package.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
I have played piano for \pgfmathparse{int(\year-1986)}\pgfmathresult~years.
\end{document}
```